# How to select a row of campaign, that has the lowest amount of rows with specific 'state'?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

There is a table like this:

`id` `campaignId` `state`

`id` - integer, `campaignId` - integer, `state` - either `todo` or `done`

How can I select a row, which state is 'todo' but also of the campaign, that has the lowest amount of rows with state 'done'?

I am currently using this, but I need to integrate that second part:

```
SELECT * FROM `original_articles` WHERE `state` = 'todo' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Your last column should be a boolean `isDone`

Comment: could be, but there are more states, that don't influence this question, e.g. `error`

Comment: can you show some sample input and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to find a query to return the campaign with the lowest amount of todo.

```
SELECT campaignId FROM original_articles
WHERE state='done'
GROUP BY campaignId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Then use it as a subquery inside your main query.

```
SELECT * FROM original_articles
WHERE
state = 'todo'
AND  campaignId IN (
    SELECT campaignId FROM original_articles
    WHERE state='done'
    GROUP BY campaignId
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: This IS a single request. The request simply has a subrequest.

Answer (score 0):

could be  this

```
SELECT *  FROM original_articles
WHERE state='todo'
and campainId = ( select campainId from 
                 FROM original_articles                               
                WHERE state='doe'                        
GROUP BY campaignId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
LIMIT 1 )
```